# microsoft ftp ls wrong filename result

Tags: iis, character-encoding, ftp, ls

When creating a file in my ftp directory with the following name:

$^_°9+[µù§@é'(².txt

the name returned when I use 'ls' is this:

$^_░9+[Á¨º@Ú'(▓.txt

the UTF-8 is enabled.
How can I fix this to get a correct name

Comment: 1) Off-topic 2) You have to first investigate if the problem is on local or remote side and tell us.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/850848

Comment: I use local command line to connect to the ftp page. so remote would be the microsoft ftp running on my machine and local would be the cmd.
And chcp 65001 does not help it doesn't even display half the characters anymore when I put the get command. And most of the time quickedit mode wont paste the filename to the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

```
mkdir $^_°9+[µù§@é'(².txt
```

The above command creates the `$^_°9+[µù§@é'(².txt` folder on the FTP server.

Windows 10 IIS server. Windows 10 `ftp.exe` client.

My FTP script is obviously in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I am running on windows 7 might be an issue in the older version only, I made the file manually it is when I 'ls' that the name is displayed wrongly

Comment: 1) Did you try a UTF-8 script instead? 2) Did you check the file locally (using Windows Explorer) on the server, if it has the correct name? 3) If you create a file in Windows Explorer on the server with a correct name, does it display correctly in `ftp.exe`? - Again, do some research and provide us more information before asking!!